# Center an HTML Table in a 90% width Div

Tags: html, css

I have a container div that is set to 90% width. I have a table that goes inside it that I would like to be centered.

What is the best cross browser way to accomplish this (including IE6)

Preferably html and css only.

Comment: table is gonna be static or dynamic width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want: http://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables/

Answer (score 0):

```
table#yourtable {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```